# How to drop rows in a Dataframe based on whether or not a cell in that row. under a particular column is empty?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the. following. dataframe.

```
A. B. C. D. E. F G 
1.    2. 3. 4
5  6  7. 8  9
1. 2  3. 4. 5
```

Here, since the cell under column B of row 1 is empty, I would like to drop row 1. It does not matter whether or not columns F and G are empty or not. The rows can be random. What matters is that if any cell under column B is empty, I want to drop the row the cell belonngs to.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: `df.loc[df['B'].notna()]`.

Answer (score 1):

@user1234,
If you just wanted to drop the first row, where df is your dataframe, you could do something like this.

```py
   new_df = df.drop(df.index[0])
```

Based on your updated comment, you could do something like this:

```py
   new_df = df.dropna(how='any', subset=['B'])
```

Comment: The rows can be random. What matters is that if any cell under column B is empty, I want to drop the row the cell belonngs to